# Populating data in Neo4j from Map Reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, neo4j, hbase

I want to use Neo4j for my project as a graph DB. All the data I have is on Hbase from which I have to get the nodes and relationships on Neo4j.

Can you please tell me the best possible way to do so? And also I want that if somehow I can use some middle layer, like map reduce writes some file and then neo4j is populated with bulk write from that file, I want this because my Kerberos is not working after Java 7 update from Java 6.

So I want to use 2 different systems for it, one for Hbase to file (with only Java 6 as present there) and other one file to Neo4j (this system will have Java 7 as Neo4j requires).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good way would be to dump data in csv format in terms on nodes and relationships and then use neo4j batch importer. Neo4j batch importer for those files. Batch importer won't take a long to generate neo4j graph.

And

It's easy to modify your hadoop program to generate output in nodes and relationships way (csv form). Yes, whatever I have written seems a bit cryptic but here's a really good example and a way to do it.

http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/02/28/batch-importer-part-1/

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hey I am thinking of populating graph one time from batch importer, and then after for incremental growth I can use REST API, is it fine to do this ?

Comment: Yup. that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Ohkie I will test it and will tell you if it works :)

Comment: If you're getting started with Neo4j 2.1 you might want to look at the new impl for the batch-importer https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/superfast-batch-importer#binary-download